# From a struct automatically define types and implement traits based on a list of arrays that contain combinations of the struct's fields

Tags: rust, macros

I got help with writing derivative types that represent the data of a struct-type `DataHolder` in a certain way. I want to have a program where new of these `DataHolder`-like types can be added so that each can have a number of different outputs. The way of defining these outputs is by defining a type like `AsSomething<'a>(&'a Dataholder)` that returns `DataHolder`'s date in a specific way. The example is here:

```rust
// this is one example of a `DataHolder` - there will exist multiple 
// in the program and each will have its own set of `As?`-types
struct DataHolder {
    num_1: u32,
    num_2: u32,
}

pub trait GimmeData<const N: usize> {
    fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; N];
}

struct AsA<'a>(&'a DataHolder);
impl<'a> GimmeData<1> for AsA<'a> {
    fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; 1] {
        [self.0.num_1]
    }
}

struct AsB<'a>(&'a DataHolder);
impl<'a> GimmeData<2> for AsB<'a> {
    fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; 2] {
        [self.0.num_2, self.0.num_1.pow(2)]
    }
}

struct AsC<'a>(&'a DataHolder);
impl<'a> GimmeData<3> for AsC<'a> {
    fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; 3] {
        [
            self.0.num_2,
            self.0.num_1.pow(2),
            self.0.num_2 * self.0.num_1,
        ]
    }
}

pub fn use_data<const N: usize, T: GimmeData<N>>(t: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", t.gimme());
}

fn main() {
    let x = DataHolder { num_1: 3, num_2: 4 };
    use_data(&AsA(&x));
    use_data(&AsB(&x));
    use_data(&AsC(&x));
}
```

In my program there will be different modules that each have their own `DataHolder`-type with a number of `As?`-types (that impl the `GimmeData<N>`-trait). Think like this:

```rust
mod module_1 {
    DataHolder { /* some fields */ }

    AsA<'a>(&'a DataHolder);
    impl<'a> GimmeData<1> for AsA<'a> {
        fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; 1] {
            [ /* something - e.g. */ 1]
    }
    AsB<'a>(&'a DataHolder);
    impl<'a> GimmeData<3> for AsB<'a> {
        fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; 3] {
            [ /* something else with 3 elements */]
    }
    
}

mod module_2 {
    DataHolder { /* some different fields */ }

    AsA<'a>(&'a DataHolder);
    impl<'a> GimmeData<9> for AsA<'a> {
        fn gimme(&self) -> [u32; 9] {
            [ /* something with 9 elements */]
    }
    AsB ... 
    AsC ...
}

// ...

mod module_n {
   DataHolder 
   AsA ... AsX
}
```

Now I would like to be able to simply add new of these `DataHolder`-types and have each of these types have their own `AsSomething`-types - like in the 2nd code-block. The thing that makes my head hurt a little is that at another place in my program I want to have a match that uses each of the `AsSomething`-types for each `DataHolder`-like types in a separate arm. I tried to make a mockup, but there might be some errors due to me not completely understanding everything:

```rust
// the thing that uses the data later
struct MuchData<const N: usize, D: GimmeData<N>> {
    data_points: Vec<[u32;N]>,
}

pub trait AnalyzeUseSomethingData {
    fn analyze(&self) -> u32; 
}

impl<const N: usize, D: GimmeData<N>> AnalyzeUseSomethingData for MuchData<N, D: GimmeData<N>> {
    fn analyze(&self) -> u32 { /* something */}
}

// something like this
fn create_data_object( /* ??? */ ) -> Box<dyn UseAsSomethingData> {
    match /* ??? */ { // this could also be two nested matches
        // create a match arm for each of the following 
        for "module" in "List of modules with DataHolder types" {
            for "AsSomething" in "List of AsSomething-types that impl `GimmeData`" {
                (module::DataHolder, AsSomething-type) => {
                    Box::new(MuchData { data_points: Vec<AsSomething>::new()})
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have two problems:

1. I need to automatically use all the `AsSomething`-types that are defined for a specific `DataHolder`. But one DataHolder can have only `AsA` and another might have 10 (`AsA` until `AsJ` or something). So it would be more convenient to have a list of arrays and have macro generate another `As?`-type. But I don't understand how such a macro could even be written. It would somehow take a list of arrays and transform it into these `As?`-types one for each element: `([self.data],[self.data.powi(2), self.data / 2], [...], .. ) -> (As?<'a>(&Dataholder) etc`.
2. I would need to have the compiler "know" for each DataHolder, how many `As?`-structs exist (that impl `gimme_data`) and make a match arm for each.

Edit:
Here is a [link](https://github.com/exo-cortex/dynamical_system_in_rust/blob/main/main_program/src/dynamical_system.rs) to my program where I defined a trait and [here](https://github.com/exo-cortex/dynamical_system_in_rust/blob/main/main_program/src/lang_kobayashi.rs) is one simple type that implements it. Right now there is only one method that returns data called `keep_state`. But I want N types of keep state and I want each be accessible at runtime.

A more understandable example could be this:

module1 is a gravitational 3-body-system (3 planets influencing each other) where `DataHolder` holds the 3 coordinates and 3 velocities per body of mass - resulting in 18 variables within `DataHolder`. One `As?` might return only coordinates of body 1, another only the X-coordinates of each body, a third only the total kinetic energy of the system.

module2 is a double pendulum and `DataHolder` holds 2 angles and 2 angular velocities and there's another set of `As?`'s that each use a combination of variables within `DataHolder`.

In the end the program decides at runtime which system to simulate and which result to use.

Comment: Can you show the `match`?

Comment: I added two code blocks for illustration. The last block has some mockup of a match statement, that could be used to initialize a struct which holds this data. 
My idea is that if this match statement is created automatically people can add new modules with `DataHolder`s later without needing to change other parts of the code.

Comment: What do you want to do within those match arms with the types? How do we decide which arm we want? Depending on that we may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I have a program that integrates dynamical systems over time. The "state" of the evolves over time and it must impl certain traits in order to be used with the integration methods (runge kutta 4). Each of these Systems is a 'DataHolder' and for each timestep the data is saved, but depending on the System there can exist a multitude of different save-methods (-> 'As?'). In the end I want to specify at runtime which "system" to simulate and which 'As?' to use to write out the data (and analyze it). (I made an edit and posted a link to relevant parts in my program).

Comment: And why exactly is listing all the `DataHolder`s and their `As` types by hand in the `match` not an option?

Comment: It could be possible, but then I would likely have to do it. In my mind it would be great if others could add `DataHolder`'s and `As?`'s that impl required traits and then the rest is done automatically. Otherwise each additional `DataHolder` would require changes somewhere else. 
Maybe I'm overthinking or -engineering it, but I mainly want to learn new tricks in Rust.

Comment: Do you want all `AsX` to be in the same place as their `DataHolder`, or even in different places?

Comment: All `AsX`'s that belong to `DataHolder` would be in the same module.